# How to install games on 64bit linux mint with updated graphics?

Tags: 64-bit, linux-mint, intel-graphics

I am using Linux Mint 11 64 bit version, and I recently installed Counter strike Condition Zero. However the game performance is extremely poor.

```
 wine "C:\Program Files\Valve\hl.exe" -nomaster -game czero 
fixme:d3d_caps:select_card_intel_mesa Card selection not handled for Mesa Intel driver
fixme:d3d_caps:init_driver_info Unhandled vendor 8086.
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f364,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:d3d_caps:select_card_intel_mesa Card selection not handled for Mesa Intel driver
fixme:d3d_caps:init_driver_info Unhandled vendor 8086.
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x32f380,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:x11drv:X11DRV_desktop_SetCurrentMode Cannot change screen BPP from 32 to 16
fixme:shdocvw:ViewObject_SetAdvise (0x1e7230)->(1 00000002 0xf27d10)
```

I later came to know that I needed 32 bit graphics drivers. I have onboard graphics chipset 945G from Intel Corp

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
Mesa: Initializing x86-64 optimizations
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 945G 
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 7.12-devel (git-eab201b natty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL extensions:
```

and I want to install the correct drivers for my game to run. Can you tell me how to install them and also in case of source tell me how to compile and install.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same Integrated graphics as you and HAD the same problem.  Do what these guys did and it will instantly solve your problem.

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=67231

You will have to update these packages to the version there or better

```
libdrm2_2.4.26-1~bpo60+1_i386.deb
libdrm-intel1_2.4.26-1~bpo60+1_i386.deb
libgl1-mesa-dri_7.10.3-4~bpo60+1_i386.deb
libgl1-mesa-glx_7.10.3-4~bpo60+1_i386.deb
libglu1-mesa_7.10.3-4~bpo60+1_i386.deb
libpciaccess0_0.12.0-1_i386.deb
```

You might also need `libglapi-mesa`

Comment: I'm out of touch with how debian derivatives relate to each other. Would the current version of the packages in that version of mint do, or do you need to enable some other repository?

Comment: I've tried this on both Ubuntu, Mint, LMDE with 100% success.  These libs are shared between them.

Comment: Ahh, good. I've taken the liberty of editing in the names of the packages in question. In future, you might want to have some additional details, least enough that should your link go down, people still have access to this information.